# How to open a another app using its package ID through web-intent from ionic app and send-receive data

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, webintents

1. I'm using Ionic Web-Intent
2. Using receiver app's package Id

Plugins

- ionic cordova plugin add com-darryncampbell-cordova-plugin-intent
- npm install --save @ionic-native/web-intent

**Im able to Open Another App,**
*here is the androidManifest.xml configration*

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.darryncampbell.cordova.plugin.intent.ACTION" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="http://webintents.org/share" />
                <action android:name="com.example.ACTION_SEND_DATA" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

*here is the code in .ts file*

```
const options : IntentOptions = {
        package : 'io.mlite.hwc_assam_uat',
        action: 'io.mlite.hwc_assam_uat.SEND_DATA',
        type: 'text/plain',
        extras: {
            'extra_key': 'extra_value'
        }
};
this.webIntent.startActivity(options).then(intent => {
    console.log(intent);
})
```

**But not able to send and receive data**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the above plugin is maintained. however, you can use [https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin#3-installation)  or
[capacitor share](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/share) plugin if you just want to share to data to other installed apps

for cordova : `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing`

for capacitor : `npm install @capacitor/share`